# Android Market - Error While Uploading APK file

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk

Just now I have developed an application and now I am ready to upload it to Android market,
but when I am trying to upload, it shows the following error message:

> Market does not accept apk signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for atleast 50 years. Market requires that the certificated used to sign the apk be Valid until at least October 22, 2033. Create a new Certificate.

Now how do I fix this problem, so that I can upload the APK file to Android market successfully?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While developing and testing, you can compile in debug mode(debug certificate).

When your application is ready for release, you must compile in release mode and then sign the .apk with your private key.

The following link gives will help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: i was knowing it but forgot to create new keystore and sign the application with new certificate, by the way, your answer made light in my mind , thanx for quick reply

Comment: The problem is the doc states that a validity of 25 years is required while the error message says it should be 50 years.