# How to sign application with existing .cer, .p12 or .pfx certificate?

Tags: android, signing

I want to sign Android app with the same certificate used for the desktop app. I have 3 files - .cer, .p12 and .pfx. Is it possible to use any of those for signing Android app?

**Update**: I have successfully imported the .cer key (which appears to be X.509-format certificate) into the newly created keystore, but I can't use it for signing. Here's the error message `jarsigner` gives me:

> Certificate chain not found for: [alias].  key must reference a valid
>   KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public
>   key certificate chain.

Perhaps, there's something else I must do with a keystore after importing the certificate to make it valid? Generate a public key or something?

Comment: Is your cert valid for 10 years or more? The Android market requieres a huge long period. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985419/how-do-i-create-a-certificate-for-my-android-market-apk

Comment: @rekire: Thanks for the heads-up! BTW, the autogenerated cert (which I got after following the tutorials on web) is only valid for 6 months. Weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing apk with .p12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829630/signing-apk-with-p12)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the keystore with -validity then this issue will appear, remove the -validity. It will work.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  certificate/xxxxx.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore certificate/xxxxx.keystore  -deststoretype JKS **-validity 36500**
```

Change to

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  certificate/xxxxx.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore certificate/xxxxx.keystore  -deststoretype JKS
```

I had this issue it got sorted because of trying to add validity to a pfx which has valid expiry date.