# How can I make a .keystore file from my own certificate on Android?

Tags: android, certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do I Create A Certificate For My Android Market APK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985419/how-do-i-create-a-certificate-for-my-android-market-apk)

I want to create my own .keystore file from a certificate. how might I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a keystore with the dialog, yes. After navigating to the folder you want to use, type a name in the 'File name:' field in the file browse window, e.g. sophie.keystore. Then you should be able to proceed.

Alternatively, you can create it on the command line as described in the docs.

The command looks like this:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

for example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/dcaunt.keystore -alias dcaunt -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```