# how can I upload my application to android market

Tags: android

I have an .apk file.I want to upload my application to android market,without using eclipse.
I have already signin.but I am getting an error.that is..**

**M*arket does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.*****

thank you

Comment: please follow the instructions carefully...i uploaded using this way
http://www.blogrocket.com/android-market-instructions

Comment: [watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou8yJvI8HCE&feature=related) and do accordingly.
Best Of Luck

Comment: I follow this tutotrial see this http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/ch08_id35815995.html . Hope this will help you .

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853140/android-market-error-while-uploading-apk-file

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Self Signed certificate

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Answer (score 0):

The error itself describe what's the problem,

**M*arket does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.***

Sign your application with your **private release key**.

Then upload it, Also put Valid years are more then 50 years..

Visit this link [Publishing on Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)